# Druid Cluster going into Restricted Mode

Tags: druid

We have a Druid Cluster with the following specs

```
3X Coordinators & Overlords - m5.2xlarge
6X Middle Managers(Ingest nodes with 5 slots) - m5d.4xlarge
8X Historical - i3.4xlarge
2X Router & Broker - m5.2xlarge
```

Cluster often goes into Restricted mode
[image: Druid Cluster Services Restricted Mode]

> 1. All the calls to the Cluster gets rejected with a 502 error.
> 2. Even with 30 available slots for the index-parallel tasks, cluster only runs 10 at time and the other tasks are going into waiting state.
> 3. Loader Task submission time has been increasing monotonically from 1s,2s,..,6s,..10s(We submit   a job to load the data in S3), after
>    recycling the cluster submission time decreases and increases again
>    over a period of time

We submit around 100 jobs per minute but we need to scale it to 300 to catchup with our current incoming load

Cloud someone help us with our queries

> 1. Tune the specs of the cluster
> 2. What parameters to be optimized to run maximum number of tasks in parallel without increasing the load on the master nodes
> 3. Why is the loader task submission time increasing, what are the parameters to be monitored here

Comment: Hard to say with that level of information.
One item that is odd, why 5 worker slots when an m5d,4xlarge has 16 CPUs, rule of thumb ( https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration/index.html#middlemanager-configuration) would say to use 15 worker slots for each.

Comment: @SergioFerragut we could have increased the worker slots but the cordinator CPU utilization is constanly around 90% with 75% slots utilization, any insights on that?

Comment: The coordinator is in charge of balancing and replicating published segments. In theory it should not affect ingestion processing which is being managed by the overlord leader process. So I'm not sure why the coordinator is so busy. How many replicas are you using for your data sources? Are you using batch ingestion or streaming? I'm just trying to understand the workload.

Comment: We did not set any replication factory explicitly, so i assume cluster comes with a replication factor of 2 in the default_tier.
We are doing batch ingestion only, but the rate at we need to ingest is little higher. We get like 500 messages in 5 minutes, but our cluster is processing only 100 messages in 5 minutes

Comment: I see, that does seem very slow. How often are you trying to run the batch ingestion?

Comment: @SergioFerragut we submit around 100 jobs per minute we need to increase it to 300

Comment: Please update the question with the info we've discussed that describes the workload. This last comment makes it clearer why the overlord might be getting overloaded. I'll attempt an answer.

Answer (score 1):

At 100 jobs per minute, this is probably why the overlord is being overloaded.

The overlord initiates a job by communicating with the middle managers across the cluster. It defines the tasks that each middle manager will need to complete and it monitors the task progress until completion. The startup of each job has some overhead, so that many jobs would likely keep the overlord busy and prevent it from processing the other jobs you are requesting. This might explain why the time for job submissions increases over time. You could increase the resources on the overlord, but this sounds like there may be a better way to ingest the data.

The recommendation would be to use a lot less jobs and have each job do more work.

If the flow of data is so continuous as you describe, perhaps a kafka queue would be the best target followed up with a Druid kafka ingestion job which is fully scalable.

If you need to do batch, perhaps a single index_parallel job that reads many files would be much more efficient than many jobs.

Also consider that each task in an ingestion job creates a set of segments. By running a lot of really small jobs, you create a lot of very small segments which is not ideal for query performance. Here some info around how to think about [segment size optimization](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/segment-optimization.html) which I think might help.

Comment: Okay, this answers our question on submission overheads. We cannot use kafka ingestion at this point because in our event messages we only have metadata info of the S3 paths. We can probably evaluate the path of loading more data within a single job.
I would also wanted to check on the GC issues that may arise if i increase the resources on overlords?

Comment: Then I think larger jobs is the answer. If you can initiate jobs maybe once per minute where you accumulate a large list of S3 paths, you can add them to an ingestion spec as described [here](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/native-batch.html#s3-input-source). If these are lots of small files, you may even benefit from using an `index` job rather than an `index_parallel` job, because this would build larger more efficient segments by consuming the full list of files in one place, rather than distributing the files across many tasks and have each create smaller segments.

Comment: We tried with index jobs and do not see any improvement in the performance. Job submission time still takes more than expected. Any specific thing to be monitored here?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but were you able to identify what was the issue here?